# How can I search Firefox’s history, and then see links before and after

Tags: firefox

When I search Firefox’s history sidebar, and see an interesting result, I’d like to see what I did before & after that result. But the only way to see the full list will lose my search result.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question and decent context. It seems that the [History Submenus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/history-submenus/) add-on can help to an extent:

> Formerly named History Menu, this extension aims to make the History
>   menu more usable, and the history sidebar less necessary. The
>   extension adds a submenu for each day and lists all sites visited on
>   that day, rather than just the last ten sites visited… as is in the
>   standard History menu. Some of the extension's behavior may be changed
>   through its preferences.

Comment: Not helpful. Even if I knew what day the search result is from, a single day has many hundreds of links which would take like 10-15 minutes just to re-find my result.